# Python - Discord Bot saving warn into json file multiple times

Tags: python, discord.py

So I found this code on internet and I wanted to implement it to my discord bot but it seems that every user in .json file is saved multiple times. And I want to just to show this:

```
name: (user_name)
reports:
```

And this code copies that every time user warn someone.

Code:

```
    with open('reports.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  try:
    report = json.load(f)
  except ValueError:
    report = {}
    report['users'] = []

@client.command(pass_context = True)
@has_permissions(manage_roles=True, ban_members=True)
async def warn(ctx,user:discord.User,*reason:str):
  if not reason:
    await client.say("Please provide a reason")
    return
  reason = ' '.join(reason)
  for current_user in report['users']:
    if current_user['name'] == user.name:
      current_user['reasons'].append(reason)
      break
  else:
    report['users'].append({
      'name':user.name,
      'reasons': [reason,]
    })
  with open('reports.json','w+') as f:
    json.dump(report,f,indent=2)
```